# Google Chrome no longer treats " Web Apps" specially

Tags: google-chrome

I'm running Google Chrome (Dev Channel), with the `--enable-apps` flag, in both OSX and Ubuntu. I have four or five WebApps installed, and they appear in the "New Tab" page just fine.

The problem is that, before, when the feature first became available in the Dev Channel, the actual tabs hosting the webapps received special treatment; they would have 3D Dock-like look, and (more importantly) the tab bar would be hidden while using that tab.

Sometime in the last few weeks, however, it seems that the special treatment just disappeared with one of the daily updates. The webapps still show up in the New Tab page, they still work in the sense that they capture all URLs going to that webapp, and they use the right icons; but they've basically become indistinguishable from just a regularly pinned tab. The two special features mentioned above have disappeared, on both Ubuntu and OS X.

My questions are simply:

a) Does this happen to anyone else? When exactly did it begin?

b) *Why* did Google regress the feature?

c) Is there any flag I can enable to get it back?

Answer (score 1):

a) You can right click on the tab and deselect show toolbar to remove that (works on windows).
b) and c) I have no idea.